# 500 error after moving site on PyroCMS (CodeIgniter) to other server

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I just moved old site of my client to some test server.
The site is on `PyroCMS`.
I've changed database settings in `aplication/config/database.php` and changed base_url in `aplication/config/config.php` to my test site URL.

Unfortunatly site is giving me `500 error` and I don't have any error logs to see what else is to change.

Where I have to do changes to site run?

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
#AllowOverride All
#RewriteBase /wherever/pyro/is

# Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
RedirectMatch 403 ^/(application\/cache|codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

# Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There are some .htaccess issue will be there

Comment: But what kind of issue you meen?

Comment: Can you please add .htaccss code so i will check what is the issue.

Comment: First bakup your htaccess.then try to remove  .htaccess all content and check.

Comment: I've already done it but nothings changed after removing htaccess content

Comment: can you please rename htaccss and echo at top of index.php file in the root

Answer (score 0):

I use PyroCMS for almost all my clients and the same issue is in the default `.htaccess` file.

Try to remove:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

And try to add:

```
Options +symlinksifownermatch -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
```

Many hosting disable `+FollowSymLinks` for security reason.

Make sure to set `775` permission to:

- system/cms/cache
- system/cms/logs
- addons
- uploads
- assets

Also make sure to set your `env` to `PYRO_DEVELOPMENT` to see all the errors in this debug phase.

Comment: Can you tell me what is nessesery folder structure for PyroCMS? I'm wondering if i have copied all files of old site? I don't see "system" folder in my root...

Comment: You need: addons, assets, system, uploads and index.php. If you don't have `system` the site can't run

Comment: I have: "application", "codeigniter", "third_party", "uploadify" and "uploads" folders. Maybe it's some kind of custom CMS based on Pyro? Diffrents are to big

Comment: probably it's not pyrocms

Comment: It's strange... I found in config and few other files a name of PyroCMS.

Comment: where did you downloaded the cms?

Comment: I didn't download it. That is an old site of my client and someone else created it.

Comment: do you have a README.md in the root? You should be able to find the version in there. The folder structure you're describing is from a pre V1.0 version. Quite old and probably not compatible with current PHP versions.

Comment: I'm describing the latest stable release of PyroCMS which is 2.2.5